# SVG маска работает не корректно

Tags: html, css, svg, frontend

Есть SVG изображение

```
<svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                                                            <mask id="mask0" mask-type="alpha" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20">
                                                                                <path d="M10 0.788818L13.09 7.04882L20 8.05882L15 12.9288L16.18 19.8088L10 16.5588L3.82 19.8088L5 12.9288L0 8.05882L6.91 7.04882L10 0.788818Z" fill="#C4C4C4"></path>
                                                                            </mask>
                                                                            <g mask="url(#mask0)">
                                                                                <rect x="-42" y="-12" width="62" height="52" fill="#ffbe4a"></rect>
                                                                            </g>
                                                                        </svg>
```

Как обычно выглядит эта SVG и как должна  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но иногда SVG работает очень странно вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: иногда... может в каком-то браузере? или все таки иногда?

Comment: Всегда иногда , в таком же браузере , при этом может быть в одном блоке коряво отображаться а в другом уже нормально

Comment: она позиционируется скриптом?

Comment: предположу, что надо уникальные идентификаторы для масок

Comment: может быть надо поместить маску между defs ?